# define a loss function

Tags: r, optimization, loss-functions

I have multiple years of temperature data. In each year, a crop is planted on day 1 and the day of the harvest is determined by a parameter `gdd`. When the cumulative sum of daily temperature crosses the `gdd` value, a crop is matured on that day.

```
set.seed(124)
weather_data <- data.frame(Year = rep(1990:2010, each = 365),
                             doj_seq = rep(1:365, times = 21),
                             temp = sample(0:40, replace = T, 21 * 365))
```

I have a starting value of `gdd` equal to 600. Using this value, I calculate for each year how long it takes for the crop to mature.

```
library(dplyr)
  
gdd <- 600
  
temp_df <- 
  
    weather_data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(Year) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(cum_temp = cumsum(temp)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(row_number() == which.max(cum_temp >= gdd)) %>%
    ungroup()
    
day_of_harvest <- temp_df$doj_seq  
day_of_harvest
[1]   36 29 28 33 27 25 28 32 31 32 26 32 29 33 30 31 31 33 30 32 30
```

From crop theory, I know that the crop should take between 60 to 90 days to mature

```
min_day <- 60
max_day <- 90
```

whereas using the `gdd`, I am getting different days to maturity in each year,     hence I need to change the value of `gdd` such that I get the required days to maturity every year that falls within the `min_day` and `max_day`.

In order to do this, I thought I will use `optim` function as follows.

```
  days_to_mature_func <- function(weather_df, gdd){
    
    temp_df <- 
      
      weather_df %>%
      dplyr::group_by(Year) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(cum_temp = cumsum(temp)) %>%
      dplyr::filter(row_number() == which.max(cum_temp >= gdd)) %>%
      ungroup()
    
    day_of_harvest <- temp_df$doj_seq  
    return(day_of_harvest)
  }
  
  optim_function <- function(x){
      
    mod <- days_to_mature_func(weather_data, x)
    
    # since the optim function needs an error to minimise, I was confused on how to define an error here. My best attempt is:
    
    mod_v <- ifelse(mod < min_day, min_day - mod, ifelse(mod > max_day, mod - max_day, 0))
    
    mean(mod_v)
  }
  
  opt_gdd <- optim(gdd, optim_function, method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = gdd + 1000)
  opt_gdd$par
  # 1597.668
```

My question is the error to use. I defined `mean(mod_v)`. It penalizes values above 90 or below 60. Is it correct for my problem statement?

Comment: What you are presenting is an equation involving three constants, how is it a cost function?

Comment: I am fairly new to this so that's why it was a poor attempt to show what my problem statement is.

Comment: Maybe try describing in plain English what is your data and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Okay let me do this. thank you for your feedback

Comment: Hello. I have rewritten my question and this time also given a background, some prelim results. Thank you for your patience

Comment: One problem is that you’ve set your max to 60 and your min to 90. I assume that’s backwards.

Comment: yes that was a typo. I have corrected it